# Wordpress - ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED when not logged in to WP-Backend

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I have a Wordpress-instance on my local XAMPP. Now under `Preferences` I changed the `Wordpress URL` to my LAN-IP, so I could access it from a other PC on my LAN.

But when I try to access it, now I get this curious 
`ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`
.. but when I login to the WP-Backend from the same machine I try to access, it works.

Does someone have a idea, what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure your local site to your IF to access to another PC on your LAN then follow some step.

1. Go to XAMPP control Panel.
2. go Apache config option.
3. Open httpd.conf file.
4. Put your ip on httpd.conf and remove # from start of line and save file.
5. restart your XAMPP server and put IP on url with project folder.

[image]

Here you have to replace url from wp_options table home, siteurl from option_name field.

Comment: When I put my IP at this point in the `httpd.conf` my Apache won't start. Removing/comment it makes Apache start again.